# Error in compiling the kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to compile linux 3.5.2 kernel. I followed this tutorial 
"http://blog.techveda.org/index.php/adding-system-calls-linux-kernel-3-5-x/"

and everything was going perfect.but when I tried to do build the kernel I get this error 
here are the commands I used to build my kernel

```
sudo cp /boot/config-3.5.0-17-generic ./config
make oldconfig
sudo make -j8
```

the error when I do the make -j8 is:

```
ERROR: "__modver_version_show" [drivers/staging/rts5139/rts5139.ko] undefined!
WARNING: modpost: Found 2 section mismatch(es).
To see full details build your kernel with:
'make CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y'
make[1]: *** [__modpost] Error 1
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I really can't find what is the problem it looks like I have a problem with a driver but how could this happen and I am using my old configuration file that is already working. ??

Comment: BTW, on Debian and related systems, you could use `make-kpkg`

Comment: what is the difference ??? and I don't think I should use it.. I used to compile the kernel without make-kpkg..

Comment: What about to simple `make mrproper` prior to any other action?

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem while compiling kernel 3.2, and solve it by "su -" to root and then recompile.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need this driver simply mod the config fiel like follows:

```
 CONFIG_RTS5139=n
```

Comment: how do I know if I need this driver or not .. and how I exactly know what this driver does actually ??

Comment: @I.el-sayed: You might like to look it up in `drivers/staging/rts5139/Kconfig`.

Comment: @l.el-sayed.  `ERROR: "__modver_version_show" [drivers/staging/rts5139/rts5139.ko] undefined!` has nothing to do with the changes you made so Check whether the kernel is building without making any changes to the kernel source. I mean without including the systemcall code.